# How to get APPLICATION_ENV in Twig for Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, twig, development-environment

How can I use `APPLICATION_ENV` in the Zend Framework Twig file?
For example in a controller we can use

```
if (APPLICATION_ENV == 'development') {
  ..
}
```

How can I write the same in a Twig file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `APPLICATION_ENV` is a constant, you can access it through Twig's [constant function](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/functions/constant.html)

Comment: Thank you so much!